# Calling C# dll in C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

My current requirement is to call some methods of C# dll in c++ console application. I have a sample C# console application code which is calling the methods from the c# dll.

C# dll was added as a reference into the C# console application project.

```
using CSharp;

void fn()
{
string retVal;
CSharpApi obj = new CSharpApi("Something");
retVal = obj.Invoke("Something");
obj.Dispose();
....
....
}
```

The definition of CSharpApi

```
namespace CSharp
{
    public class CSharpApi : IDisposable
    {
        public CSharpApi();
        public CSharpApi(string param1);
        public string Invoke(string param1);
        public void Dispose();
    }
}
```

I need to write a c++ console application equivalent to the above c# console application but not sure how to achieve it. Is is possible to call C# dll methods using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress APIs? I would be very grateful if you could give me some examples.

Comment: Why not make a C++/CLI managed .NET application?

Comment: Although I didn't know that this is possible, there is apparently a [tutorial by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736) covering the subject.

Answer (score 0):

As Joachim alludes in his comment, the most straightforward way to do it is to use [C++/CLI managed .NET aplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx), it gives you the best of both worlds, you can still write most of your code in unmanaged way, and you have a relatively simple way to call into managed code too.